# Modular Database Initialization

Tags: java, database, jpa, liquibase

While working on a modular system architecture for an enterprise application I run into some problems with database initialization. We have a core library that provides base entities and base configuration. On top of this core several modules are build. They are pluggable and can have their own entities and configuration. Some characteristics:

- Configuration, like system properties, resourcebundles, etc, are all stored in the database.
- JPA is used to make the system database independent.
- System runs on Java SE

Every module can bring its own tables, but they can also require to populate the core property table, or the core resourcebundle table. So somehow we need some mechanisme to run a DDL and DML initialization for the database. Some options:

1. Create simple sql scripts. Disadvantage is that they must be database independent and perhaps this is not the most developer friendly. Unless we can generate them with some DB diff tool?
2. Use Java classes to initialize via JPQL?
3. Store configuration in files? This avoids a lot (but not all) of configuration DML.
4. Use some tool like liquibase?

What would be the best practice for this (or a similar) problem?

Comment: You've tagged this post with liquibase... Doesn't this tool help you?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor it could be an option. But I'm looking into a best practice approach here. So if there are other / better approaches then I'm happy to learn about them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database for store all configuration data is the best option. Many products, such as WebSphere Portal or Liferay use a database to store the configuration data for each portlet or even for theme. Don't forget to include those that are used as part of an SOA and Business Rules.

Therefore, the use of SQL scripts is also the best choice. However, if you require very specific features of SQL, you may need to create *several* versions of same script for each database management system.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently in an project that has the same idea of modules that add functionality to a core system.

Generally we are using maven and multiple `src` folders as well as maven profiles and different builds to be able to generate a deployable with different modules. (we do not have the necessity to push out single modules and install them later on - this might be different in your project. We just build different versions with different modules.)

Anyway, for the DB we are using liquibase. Firstly to manage the DB and the changes done to it. But also (and this might be helpful to you) to include/generate another SQL script that adds tables for the modules.

Each module has its own changeset-file that includes everything that is necessary for that module (also in different versions as the modules evolve through time). These can then be applied or not.

So, I think liquibase could also be useful in your case (even though it's main purpose is to manage DB changes).